# Why is finalize lifted in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I am having trouble understanding the [finalize](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator in RxJS. Let me demonstrate this on an example:

```
of(null).pipe(
  tap({ complete: () => console.log('tap 1 completes') }),
  finalize(() => console.log('finalize')),
  tap({ complete: () => console.log('tap 2 completes') })
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('subscribe completes') });
```

I would expect the `finalize` callback to be executed before the second `tap`. That's not happening, though. Rather the above code produces the following output:

```
tap 1 completes
tap 2 completes
subscribe completes
finalize
```

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/finalize.ts) I believe the operator is passed (*lifted*) through the whole observable chain to always be applied at its end. So now I end up with two questions:

1. What's the rationale behind this design decision? Can you give some explanation on why this is a desireable / advantageous property?
2. Is there a different operator or other solution to execute code on complete and on error, but *in order* (i.e. before the second `tap` in the above example) rather than at the end of the observable chain?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/5433

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to be aware that `finalize()` and `tap()` work very differently. `tap()` is triggered by `next`, `error` and `complete` notifications while `finalize()` is only triggerd on chain ubsubscription. In other words `finalize()` is very similar to using:

```
const subscription = $source.subscribe();
// This will be always triggered after all `tap()`s
subscription.add(() => console.log('same as finalize()'));
```

So you can't make `finalize()` to be invoked before `tap()`. Also, be aware that `finalize()` is invoked also when you manually unsubscribe liek the following:

```
subscription.unsubscribe(); // will always invoke `finalize()` but never `tap()`
```

One possible solution could be implementing you own `finalize()` variant that knows the reason why it's being called: https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra/blob/master/doc/finalizeWithReason.md [(see source code)](https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra/blob/master/src/operators/finalizeWithReason.ts)

Also note, that https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/5433 will have no affect on your use-case.

Comment: Interesting! So far I thought of `finalize` as an RxJS equivalent of `Promise.finally`. Apparently there's much more going on under the hood here.

Answer (score 4):

That's the whole principle of the `finalize` operator. To emit only -after- the source observable completes. Which does mean, after all the complete subscriptions have been handled, counting the `tap` complete. From the docs:

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, but will call a specified function when the source terminates on complete or error.

Now you could place the `finalize` in an inner observable, but I suppose you wouldn't like the order then either

```
of(null).pipe(
  tap({ complete: () => console.log('tap 1 completes') }),
  concatMap((resp) => of(resp).pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize'))
  )),
  tap({ complete: () => console.log('tap 2 completes') })
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('subscribe completes') });
```

This will make the `finalize` execute before the first and last tap, this is because of the `complete` object you pass into `tap`. If you just pass in a function in the first `tap`, it will have the right order.

Another way could be the usage of `concat`:

```
concat(
  of(null).pipe(
    tap({complete: () => console.log('tap 1 completes' ) }),
    finalize(() => console.log('finalize'))
  ),
  EMPTY.pipe(
    tap({complete: () => console.log('tap 2 completes' ) })
  )
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('subscribe completes') });
```

But this kinda prevents you from accessing what ever the first observable emitted. So, basically, I don't think there is a proper solution to what you are asking :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! By now I think I'm actually searching for a variant of `tap`, rather than a variant of `finalize`. I guess I can just define that myself: `const tapOnEnd = callback => tap({ complete: () => callback(), error: () => callback() })`.

Comment: @kremerd I'm kind of sure that the `finalize` will be called after that as well

Comment: You're right. I mean to use it instead of the `finalize` operator, though, not instead of the other `tap`s. This way the execution order should be straight as it's just dealing with a sequence of `tap`s.

Comment: I forgot about that, when an observable errors, it will call `complete` as well. If you want these functions to be the same, you should just use the `complete`. Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kehls) (i've implemented your `tapOnEnd`)

Comment: I don't think that `complete` is called on errors. I also tried it in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dlx587), and only the `error` callback is called. Maybe I'm missing something, though. That "here" link is broken, so I haven't been able to check your implementation.

Comment: @kremerd I'm sorry, missed the last character. Here it [is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kehlsj)